# How to remove underline from dropdown menu material design in android

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design, android-textinputlayout, material-components-android

I can't seem to get rid of the black underline from [Exposed Dropdown Menu](https://material.io/design/components/menus.html#exposed-dropdown-menu) done according to material design guide in my android UI.

The dropdown looks like this:

[image]

I have tried setting background to null, transparent or custom shape. `app:boxBackgroundMode="none"` doesn't work either.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/spinner_age"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_rounded_button"
        android:hint="Age">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/age_dropdown"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Ideally the dropdown would look like a button without the underline. How do I get rid of it?

Comment: try this out https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/201#issuecomment-526392092

Comment: please share your file code : @ drawable/bg_rounded_button

Answer (score 1):

Please change your this line

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

With

```
android:background="#00000000"
```

Comment: It is not correct. Check the doc. If EditText child that is not a TextInputEditText, make sure to set the EditText's android:background to @null

Answer (score 1):

Setting `boxStrokeWidth = 0dp` would solve it

Answer (score 0):

Make background = null

```
 <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/age_dropdown"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

just add this line to remove the underline

```
  android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [**standard** style](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TextInputLayout.md#filled-box-default) `@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu` and

You don't need to use a custom background shape, you can just use the
**`app:boxCornerRadius*`** attributes to define the rounded shape.

Something like:

```
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
            app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="32dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="32dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="32dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="32dp"
            app:boxStrokeColor="@color/myselector"
            ...>

              <AutoCompleteTextView
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:background="@null"
                  />


        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

To change the color of the line under the component, you have to change the **`app:boxStrokeColor`** attribute. Just customize the selector as you prefer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:alpha="0" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface" android:state_hovered="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface" android:state_enabled="false"/>
  <item android:alpha="0" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface"/>
</selector>
```

This is the result:

[image]

Pay attention to this [note](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TextInputLayout.md#filled-box-default) in doc:

> Note: When using a filled text field with an `EditText` child that is **not** a `TextInputEditText`, make sure to set the `EditText`'s `android:background` to `@null`. This allows `TextInputLayout` to set a filled background on the `EditText`.

**Alternative:**
With the new version 1.1.0 you can also use the **`shapeAppearanceOverlay`** attribute to [customize the shape](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Shape.md) of your component.

Just use:

```
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            style="@style/MyFilledBox_ExposedDropdownMenu
            ...>

              <AutoCompleteTextView
                  android:background="@null"
                  ... />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

and this style:

```
  <!-- Rounded -->
  <style name="MyFilledBox_ExposedDropdownMenu" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu">
    <item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.TextInputLayout.Rounded</item>
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/myselector</item>
  </style>

  <style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.TextInputLayout.Rounded" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">32dp</item>
  </style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer! Strangely enough, I tried your solution and still can't get rid of the underline. Even tried it in an empty-ish new project :/

Comment: It is strange. Check the selector that you are using in the app:boxStrokeColor.